# Comparing two Dictionaries with different keys in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries containing IP addresses. E.g

```
site_scope1 = {'Servers': ['1.1.1.1', '1.1.1.2']}
```

and another which contains addresses pulled from a device which looks like

```
vlan_helpers = {'300': ['1.1.1.1', '1.1.2.2']}
```

How can I compare the two dictionaries to verify that the the 300 key in vlan_helpers contains the values in the Servers key in site_scope1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if both keys have the same value, you can directly access them and do the comparison this way:

```
if site_scope1['Servers'] == vlan_helpers['300']:
    # Do something.
```

If you just want to check if some keys of the Servers list is also in the 300 list, you can do this:

```
for item in site_scope1['Servers']:
    if item in vlan_helpers['300']:
        print('IP is in Both dicts: ', item)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [***set***](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#set-types-set-frozenset) objects:

```
result = set(site_scope1['Servers']) == set(vlan_helpers['300'])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can find which of `Serveurs` are in `300` :

```
>>> site_scope1 = {'Servers': ['1.1.1.1', '1.1.2.2']} 
>>> vlan_helpers = {'300': ['1.1.1.1', '1.1.2.2']}
>>> [x for x in site_scope1['Servers'] if x in vlan_helpers['300']]
['1.1.1.1', '1.1.2.2']

>>> site_scope1 = {'Servers': ['1.1.1.1', '1.1.1.2']} 
>>> vlan_helpers = {'300': ['1.1.1.1', '1.1.2.2']}
>>> [x for x in site_scope1['Servers'] if x in vlan_helpers['300']]
['1.1.1.1']
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, you just want to compare two `specific` elements of the dictionary.

```
site_scope1 = {'Servers': ['1.1.1.1', '1.1.1.2']}
vlan_helpers = {'300': ['1.1.1.1', '1.1.2.2']}

print(site_scope1['Servers'] == vlan_helpers['300'])
```

Output:

```
False
```

If your IP's are not ordered use `set()`:

```
print(set(site_scope1['Servers']) == set(vlan_helpers['300']))`
```